# Doesn't "I made it hard for him to do that" break the rules?

Tags: grammar

As I know construction "for+ object+ infinitive" can be used in a role of a direct object only after the particular list of verbs and adjectives like "wait for, ask for, anxious for" and so on.. But in the sentence like "I made it hard for him to do that" the real object, even if it's preceded by the formal object "it",is "for him to do that" that follow verb "made" that's outside of the list of verbs that allow to use such the construction in the form of an object.

So my question is, is it possible and grammatically correct to use the construction "for+ object+ infinitive" after any object if it's preceded by an formal object "it" And if yes then what rules do proof that?

Comment: "for + object + infinitive" cannot be a direct object ever. It's a *prepositional phrase* with an *infinitive adjunct*. The pronoun "him" is an *indirect object*. The whole phrase itself, like most prepositional phrases, is an *adjunct*.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence is well-formed. The verb "make" licences an adjective complement "hard" and the adjective licences a prepositional phrase "for him" and an infinitive "to do {something}"

Other verbs with adjective complements could have similar structures, with or without a formal object.

> It is good for Joe to read books.

> It seems sad for the flowers to die.

But more generally, many verbs don't licence an adjective complement.  You couldn't say "I eat it good for him to do something".  The verb "eat" doesn't allow for an adjective complement.

Comment: As I know the construction "for+ object+ infinitive" can be an object of a particular list of verbs (wait for, ask for). Isn't it right? Can any transitive verb have this construction as an object? Like "I want for him to go there"

Comment: No.  Transitive verbs require a direct object. "Want" in your example is being used as an intransitive verb. (and not idiomatically)  There is an idiomatic use of "want for" and it means "not have":  "I do not want for money" means "I have money"

Comment: I used it as a transitive one

Comment: No. You use "want" as an intransitive verb because in "I want for him to go there" the verb "want" doesn't have a direct object.

Comment: But I did.  "for+object+infinitive" can be used after any transitive verb as a direct object? Or not

Comment: No.  Direct objects are noun phrases, not prepositional phrases.

Comment: I think it's the adjectives alone doing the licensing of *[ for-phrase + to-phrase ]*. I can't think of a counterexample where a bare adjective is correct as a predicate adjective, but the structure "adjective + for-phrase + to-phrase" is incorrect with the same adjective -- and by "same adjective", I mean with the same meaning.

Comment: An Infinitive is in predicate relations to an subject so it's like a subordinated clause in a role of a direct object

Answer (score 0):

You state

> [The] construction "for+ object+ infinitive" can be used in a role of a direct object only after the particular list of verbs and adjective

as a rule of English. Where did you find this "rule"? I am not aware of any such rule.

I think that the sentence:

> I made it hard for him to do that.

is grammatically valid. I would say that the expression "made it hard" functions as the verb here. Some would call that a phrasal verb. That would make "for him to do that" the direct object.

By the way, "proof" is not normally used in the way the last sentence of the question uses it.

Comment: As I know  the construction "for+ object+ infinitive" can be an object of a particular list of verbs. Isn't it right? Can any transitive verb have this construction as an object? Like "I want for him to go there"

Comment: It's like rephrase of "I made for him to do it hard" With formal object "it" But not it as the main one

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand this "wait for/anxious for" rule. Because no, that's not a rule in English. Maybe if I knew the context it would at least make sense in that context.

In the example sentence you gave, let's drop the "for" clause and just consider, "I made it hard." The subject is "I", the verb is "made", the object is "it", and "hard" is an adjective that modifies "it". This sentence resembles the common subject-"is"-predicate adjective form. You are saying that "it" is "hard". But in this case, it wasn't always hard. You are saying, "I made" it hard.

Then there is a phrase that modifies "hard": "for him to do that". What is hard about it? It is hard for him to do that.

There are lots of words that could fit in a "for"+object+infinitive like this. "The tractor made the ground ready for the farmer to plant the seeds." "I positioned the target for the archer to aim at." Etc.

Comment: "for+object+infinitive" Can't be direct object of any transitive verb but only  that ones who have "for"in its composition like " Wait for"

Comment: It's like rephrase of "I made for him to do it hard" With formal object "it" But not it as the main one